# How to properly shut down Rasberri Pi Pico (windows)?

Tags: micropython

I only received my first Raspberry Pi for tinyML development and specifically its microcontroller "Pico" version. I am surprised to see no instructions on how to properly shut this thing off / eject it from the computer on a Windows 10 environment (or any environment for that matter) and since I am a complete noob with hardware stuff I am not sure that simply unplugging it is the correct way to do it. Could anyone enlighten me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do nothing special.  Just remove the power when you have finished using the Raspberry Pico.

Comment: You mean just pull it from the plug, right? I apologise for ignorance, but need to make sure I don't misunderstand anything!

Comment: Remove the power.  If the plug you are talking about supplies the power removing that plug is one way to remove the power.